# select item listbox c#

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-phone

I'm trying to use C# to select an item in a listbox using a switch statement but nothing happens:

This is my current code:

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="test" (XAML OMITED) SelectionChanged="test_SelectionChanged">
 <ListBoxItem Content="name 1" />
```

c#

```
 private void test_SelectionChanged(object sender,  System.EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (test.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            case "name 1":
                MessageBox.Show("X");
                break;
            case "name 2":
                MessageBox.Show("X");
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }
```

thanks

Comment: which line do you think is selecting the listbox item in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listbox is the sender object so you can access it like so.  You just need to cast the sender as a listbox, then your selected item is a listbox item so you would cast it and then you can access the content values. Also when I created my selectionchanged event handler it accepts SelectionChangedEventArgs e not System.EventArgs e, SelectionChangedEventArgs is found in the System.Windows.Controls Namespace, which should already be imported into your class through using statement.

```
var mySender = (ListBox)sender;
swtich(((ListBoxItem)mySender.SelectedItem).Content.ToString()){

  case "name 1":
            MessageBox.Show("X");
            break;
  case "name 2":
            MessageBox.Show("X");
            break;
  default:
            break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to call a method in some cases or update a variable?

Comment: I saw that after I posted the no need what you could do is switch on the messagebox value I am outputting I will edit for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var selectedItem in e.AddedItems)
            {
                switch ((selectedItem as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString())
                {
                    case "name 1":
                        MessageBox.Show("X");
                        break;
                    case "name 2":
                        MessageBox.Show("y");
                        break;
                    default:

                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```